# Can I move to wordpress.org and continue to be included as a wordpress.com favorite blog?

Tags: wordpress.com-hosting

I'm listed as a wordpress.com favorite blog.  If I move over to wordpress.org, will I continue to be listed as a favorite with wordpress.com?

Comment: Where exactly are you listed? In a blogroll or on a special wordpress.com page?

Comment: We're listed as a "recommended blog" here:  http://wordpress.com/#!/read/recommendations/

Comment: @Carol see updated answer

Answer (score 1):

You can try by connecting your self-hosted WordPress.org blog to the WordPress.com network using the [Jetpack](http://jetpack.me) plugin.

If that doesn't work, hosting with [WordPress.com VIP](http://vip.wordpress.com/hosting/) definitely will. Your site is still hosted on the WordPress.com network, only you have full access to it, just as if your were hosting on a different web host. It's the best of [both worlds](http://en.support.wordpress.com/com-vs-org/). From their website:

> As a WordPress.com VIP, you get all the benefits and features of WordPress’s continuously evolving platform and WordPress.com’s rock-solid infrastructure, without the burden of making sure the site is stable, maintained, and secure — that’s our job.

The only con with WordPress.com VIP is the cost - but if you can manage that, then it should be perfect for you.